# Keyboard recreation for security reason

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I need to recreate custom keyboard with four levels: lowercase, uppercase, special characters and special characters when shift is pressed. I do not want to create plist file where will be placed all characters for each level. I am looking for the solution to get it using native framework.

***What is the way to get characters set for each level?***

Characters set should depend on language. Lets say German layout is different to UK layout.

Answer to the “Why?” question: For security reason as written in [iOS Security guid](https://www.apple.com/business/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf) at p.20 it is better to present custom keyboard to the users. As my text field have functionality hide/show password my UITextView can be in the mode not secure.

> Once enabled, the extension will be used for any text field except the
>   passcode input and any secure text view.

Comment: Can you include the exact quote as to your 'why' from the pdf? All I'm finding is 'Once enabled, the extension will be used for any text field except the passcode input and any secure text view.' which indicates otherwise

Comment: @JanGreve Quote was add.

Comment: That is exactly what I quoted. You are missunderstanding that, completely. Apple **does not allow** custom keyboards for password fields because of security concerns.

Comment: My UITextView have functionality show/hide and it means that UITextView is not secure when user pressed show. As well I asked Apple security engineer about it. He wrote, that custom keyboards do provide better protection than native keyboards.

Comment: Can you show us where an Apple engineer told you a 3rd party keyboard was better than their native keyboard for password input.